# Jave while loops

Tags: java

Beginner at Java. Using Zybooks. To me the software does not teach well, its vague. 
Here is the Question:

Given positive integer numInsects, write a while loop that prints that number doubled without reaching 200. Follow each number with a space. After the loop, print a newline. Ex: If numInsects = 16, print:

16 32 64 128

Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InsectGrowth {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      int numInsects;
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      numInsects = scnr.nextInt(); // Must be >= 1

       System.out.print(numInsects + " ");

  while (numInsects <= 100) {
     numInsects = numInsects * 2;
     System.out.print(numInsects + " ");
  }

  System.out.println();

   }
}
```

Here are the results: It did not pass with 200, just left an empty space.
Testing with 16.
Your output
16 32 64 128 
Testing with 98.
Your output
98 196 
Testing with 200.
Output differs. See highlights below.
Your output
200 
Expected output

Comment: Your problem is the print before the loop starts. You only want that if numInsects is < 200, so put it in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your first print into the while loop and check for 200

```
public class InsectGrowth {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      int numInsects;
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      numInsects = scnr.nextInt(); // Must be >= 1

      while (numInsects < 200) {
          System.out.print(numInsects + " ");
         numInsects = numInsects * 2;
      }

      System.out.println();

   }
}
```

Comment: You also need to have < 200 as the problem is that it's printing out 200

Comment: Thank you everyone! I was getting so frustrated with this that I forgot and was overlooking that I had the   System.out.print(numInsects + " ");  up there while I was trying to fix other parts. Works great! This semester is the 1st time i've ever dealt with Java. In fact until basically fall semester of last year i've never coded anything. (i'm an older fart), I will have plenty more questions, as our online book quite sucks i feel.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of handling edge-case scenario. As you see, your `while` loop is exceeding the boundary condition by one iteration. So you just need to tweak the condition.

**Replace** your `while` loop with following code block:

**with**

```
     if(numInsects <= 200) {
         System.out.print(numInsects);
     }
     while (numInsects <= 100) {
         numInsects = numInsects * 2;
         System.out.print(" " + numInsects);
     }
```

Comment: shouldn't the <= 100 be  < 200?

Comment: Yeah, in one part 200 is expected.  Then before that he says "...without reaching 200"

Comment: it's not just that - it's the print before the loop

Comment: @NiteRain and pcoates, thanks guys for commenting. See the edits now.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is  seeing the current value of the numInsects and not considering what's actually  being applied.

**Example:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numInsects;
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        numInsects = scnr.nextInt(); // Must be >= 1

        System.out.print(numInsects + " ");
        /*
          is  16 less than 200? yes
          is  32  less than 200? yes
          is  64 less than 200? yes
          is  128 less than 200? yes
          is  256 less than 200? no, break

          but if
          is  16 *2  less than 200? yes
          is  32  *2  less than 200? yes
          is  64 *2  less than 200? yes
          is  128  *2 less than 200? no, break
        */

        while (numInsects * 2 < 200) {
            numInsects = numInsects * 2;
            System.out.print(numInsects + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your numInsects will be always 0, you should say int numInsects = 1;
 because your are doing this:

0*2=0
0*2=0
0 
0
0
0
0

Answer (score -1):

```
while (true) {
   numInsects = numInsects * 2;
   if (numInsects >= 200) break;
   System.out.print(numInsects + " ");
}
```

To highlight do it the way that is clearer to you and that there are multiple ways to eat a fish since you're learning, its good to learn you will run into everyone doing it differently.